# Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol. Could not resolve type T

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr, nrwl-nx

Hello I'm [trying to update](https://github.com/snebjorn/akita/tree/refactor/nx-workspace) the angular packages for the library [Akita](https://github.com/datorama/akita).

However I'm getting a very cryptic error when building after the update.

```
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: /home/runner/work/akita/akita/libs/akita-ng-forms-manager/src/lib/forms-manager.store.ts:3:1: Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'FormsStore': 
 /home/runner/work/akita/akita/libs/akita-ng-forms-manager/src/lib/forms-manager.store.ts:7:22: Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Could not resolve type T.
  {"__symbolic":"error","message":"Could not resolve type","line":6,"character":21,"context":{"typeName":"T"}}
```

[Error log](https://github.com/snebjorn/akita/runs/508950805?check_suite_focus=true)

so basically

> Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'FormsStore': Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Could not resolve type T.

All I've been able to find is this https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/641 that basically says that I should add `// @dynamic` above classes that have `static` stuff in them.
I don't have anything `static` and adding `// @dynamic` didn't resolve the issue.

I was able to make some head way, as I am able to compile when Ivy is turned on.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true
}
```

But leaving Ivy on isn't an option as it is [not recommended](https://v9.angular.io/guide/ivy#maintaining-library-compatibility) to publish Ivy libraries to NPM repositories.

Here's the relevant files

- [forms-manager.store.ts](https://github.com/snebjorn/akita/blob/refactor/nx-workspace/libs/akita-ng-forms-manager/src/lib/forms-manager.store.ts)
- [store.ts](https://github.com/snebjorn/akita/blob/refactor/nx-workspace/libs/akita/src/lib/store.ts)

Thank you for your time